# Themes / color schemes in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, software

I was wondering yesterday if there are any theme / color scheme manager for LTspice.

There are times you want it on light mode, and times when dark mode suits better. Google didn't yield any results for theming the UI, else than using Tools->Color Preferences, and setting slowly color by color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of you probably are using LTspice, and I doubt I'm not the only who have thought this thing. **Today I decided to do something about it.** It's not too fancy and it's currently only for Windows/PowerShell. It's currently bit hacky and might break in update, I'll make it better upcoming days.

https://github.com/sakabug/LTspice-themes

When LTspice is closed, you run `LTspice-themes <theme name>` in PowerShell and it replaces [Colors] section in the LTspice ini file. You can have as many themes in the LTspice-themes.txt as you wish, and you just call it with the theme name.

To create new themes, you make one with LTspice built-it palette. When ready, close LTspice. Copy [Colors] section from .ini to the themes file end. Rename [Colors] into [<theme name>] in themes file and save.

Now you can get your latets color palette just by calling `LTspice-themes <new theme>` in PowerShell.

On github page there are step by step instruction for taking it into use. Only thing you need to remember is to use the command while LTspice isn't running, because LTspice will save it's .ini on closing.

Now we can change UI colors just in few seconds. I'll be centralizing themes into the github page if people like to share their own color palettes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now there are 4 ready themes: `default, sakabug, twilight-after-dawn, dracula`

Comment: That's pretty nice. Now if only you can get it to automatically populate DC operating point parameters next to devices, automatically (like Cadence).

Comment: Well, I took the challenge. Currently I get all currents into somewhat right locations. Next ones are voltages for the nodes. Good thing is that you don't have to close LTspice, but you need to close the file to update the DATAFLAGS into .asc. Basically you need to run simulation once and keep the .raw. close file, run command, open file and update simulation. I'll continue tomorrow. It would be more automatic if I'd know how to update schematic from the .asc file without closing it.

Comment: That sounds great. I'll look into your github site. Also, ideally we could also populate small signal parameters like gm, gds, vdssat, etc..

Comment: I'll prob make it Python and just short function to pass arguments for powershell users.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using the **OSX** version of **LTSpice** I have created a new theme manager available here: https://github.com/johan162/ltspice-osx-themes

It makes it possible to both load a new pre-made theme for use in **LTSpice** but also save an existing configuration of **LTSpice** as a new theme.

> **Note:** This is for **OSX** only!

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows `.asc` File Associations (Double-Clicking):

Associating the start menu shortcut with a passed-in command line parameter (as above) will leave the `.asc` files unassociated,  i.e. double-clicking on an `.asc` file will open LTspice with its default configuration without loading the custom `.ini` file that the shortcut references.

The solution is to **create a `.bat` file and associate that with the *‘Open With…’*** Explorer menu option like so:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\XVIIx64.exe" %1 -ini "d:\AppData\LTSpiceXVII\LTspiceXVII.ini"
```

##### Addendum: General Syntax

```
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

- `title` Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
- `path` Starting directory.
- `command` The command, batch file or executable program to run.
- `parameters` The parameters passed to the command
- `%1` - stands for *passed argument #1*, i.e. the file that is being opened by our double-clicking

#### References:

- [General Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265635/6118556) - StackOverflow
- [Concrete Example](https://superuser.com/a/1233379/763152) - SuperUser