# LTspice 24 `.ini` file location

Tags: ltspice

#### Background

LTspiceXVII had a well-defined location for its `.ini` file.

LTspice17 (i.e. the successor to XVII) [stores](https://ez.analog.com/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice/w/faqs-docs/18474/ltspice-17-1-default-file-locations-windows) its `.ini` file at one of these two locations:

> - Only for me: `C:\users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\ADI\LTspice\`
> - Everybody: `C:\Program Files\ADI\LTspice\`

#### Problem

The current version of LTspice24 (as of February 2024) does not document the location for its `.ini` file, despite the fact that it is still mentioned as user-definable value under the *Command Line Switches* section of the help file that comes with it.

#### Question

Where does LTspice24 store its `.ini` configuration file?

Comment: I think your terminology is a bit confusing.  The one you call LTspice XVII, is called LTspice 17.0.  The new one you call LTspice24, is called LTspice 17.1.  This is the officially recognized version naming by Analog Devices.  For reference, here's a snip of when you try to update LTspice 17.0.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xrkc.png

Comment: @SteKulov I am indeed, confused, but I think I got my terminology straight. My old version of LTspice refers to itself as `LTspice XVII(x64) (17.0.36.0)` [link](https://imgur.com/1gMtbei), and that's how it's referenced on the analog.com website at the moment [link](https://imgur.com/a/SHrHXm4). Now roughly this time last year there was a new version out calling itself `17.1.x` [link](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/installing-the-new-2023-version-of-ltspice.394676/post-7241336) But the currently newest version has bumped version number to `24` [link](https://imgur.com/a/CWWsZ9l)

Comment: Ahhh.  Gotcha.  My mistake.  I didn't realize they just did another name change last week to 24 (I assume because 17.0 vs 17.1 was very confusing and they didn't want to call the new one 17.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. It lives under:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\
```

I only skimmed the file, but its contents look identical to that of XVII - at least as far as theming goes. Therefore custom default setting and theme colours can still be configured within this file and you can also move it to wherever you please as long as you tell LTspice24 where to look for it, using the `-ini` command-line switch.

I've written [detailed instructions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/665917/128715) on how to do this for XVII, which works fine for v24 too.

**Excerpt:**

> Associating the start menu shortcut with a passed-in command line parameter (as above) will leave the `.asc` files unassociated,  i.e. double-clicking on an `.asc` file will open LTspice with its default configuration without loading the custom `.ini` file that the shortcut references.
>
> The solution is to **create a `.bat` file and associate that with the *‘Open With…’*** Explorer menu option...

Comment: LTspice, after a long time of not following system conventions for storing initialization data, has finally got it right. The `AppData\Local` folder was a wrong choice.